# cassandra partial insert and batch insert size limit

Tags: cassandra, save, batch-processing

I need to parse tab delimited file that is posted to a queue and each record in the file needs to be saved into Cassandra to 5 different tables. I am not using batch transactions.

I am a bit apprehensive that there could be cases when the data is inserted only to 3 TABLES and not ALL 5 TABLES.

If I use batch inserts then there is a limit on the data that I can put.What approach do you think would be ideal in my case? PLEASE suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You need batch statement so that you can threat 5 tables insert as atomic operation, logged batch will give you exactly that, it is all or nothing so you will be sure that all 5 tables have data from each record after it is successfully inserted.

I would use one batch with 5 statements for one insert, and cassandra driver will do round robin to choose coordinator for each batch insert so it will distribute load to many nodes in cluster evenly.

Comment: what if I have over 2500 records and each record data needs to be persisted to 5 tables. Batch insert limit I heard is 10000.

Comment: Actually it is 65K as I remember but still as stated in other answer it is putting to much load on single node (coordinator) so it is better IMO to loop over 2500 items and put 5 statements in batch and execute immediately 2500 times, it will spread load across all nodes in cluster

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, I have been thinking so much bat this.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that "batch" in cassandra may be missleading because it treats a batch as atomic operation => coordinator node of that batch will have a lot to do.

More details here:

https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e

https://ahappyknockoutmouse.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/246/

Hint:
use **prepared statements**